# Change layout when soft keyboard is shown

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, soft-keyboard

I would like to change the layout when an EditText is clicked and the softkeyboard is shown, so all EditText views are still visible.

I know that you can use the following two, but this is not what i'm looking for.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan">
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize">
```

I've got 8 EditText views spread over the whole screen. When one is clicked to change a value I would like to still see all the ET views but nicely arrange and not pushed in a weird view.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have to do this yourself, but one technique might be ...

Create a layout with the views arranged for the keyboard shown (for instance a new RelativeLayout) that overlays your standard layout.  Set it's visibility to GONE.  Then when you detect the event that shows the keyboard hide the current view and show the alternate one

I suppose you could also use a ViewSwitcher

Answer (score 0):

If you are using both at the same time then it doesnt work.Set the attribute `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` only.That should work.